# Why will a Log expression with Quantity expressions not get simplified?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, units

I'm having trouble with numerically evaluating some functions. The problem essentially comes down to

```
Log[Quantity[3, "Meters"]] - Log[Quantity[2, "Kilometers"]]
```

The above code doesn't evaluate to a numerical answer even though it should since
$$ \log(3\ {\rm m}) - \log(2\ {\rm km}) = \log \left(\frac{3\ {\rm m}}{2\ {\rm km}} \right)=\log\left(\frac 3{2000}\right)$$
Is there a way to get mathematica to automatically combine the logs of unitful quantities?

EDIT:

Note the following:

```
Log[ Quantity[3, "Meters" ] / Quantity[2, "Kilometers"] ]
(* -Log[2000/3] *)

Simplify[ Log[a] - Log[b], b > 0]
(* Log[a/b] *)

Simplify[ Log[ Quantity[3, "Meters"] ] - Log[ Quantity[2, "Kilometers"] ] ]
(* Log[ 3 m ] - Log[ 2 km ] *)
```

Comment: `Log[QuantityMagnitude@Quantity[3, "Meters"]] - 
  Log[QuantityMagnitude@Quantity[2, "Kilometers"]] // N` could be a workaround.

Comment: @Syed - You need a `UnitConvert`, i.e., `Log[QuantityMagnitude@Quantity[3, "Meters"]] - Log[QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert@Quantity[2, "Kilometers"]] // N`

Comment: `Log[Quantity[3, "Meters"]] - Log[Quantity[2, "Kilometers"]] /. 
 Log[a_] - Log[b_] :> Log[a/b]`

Comment: Completely missed that units were different. Thanks @BobHanlon

Comment: `Log[ Quantity[3, "Meters"] ]` is undefined. The first example is unrelated because `Quantity[3, "Meters"]/Quantity[2, "Kilometers"]` evaluates to a number. So the question is comparing the logarithm of a number with logarithms of distances.

Comment: Indeed you can only arrive at $\log(a) - \log(b)$ coming from $\log(\frac{a}{b})$ when $a$ and $b$ are dimensioned quantities and this only works when the units cancel out in the fraction. A very good explanation underlining the comment by @MichaelE2 is given [here](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/General/logs.html).